# Append `0,` to all lines having 2 commas and not more than 2 commas?

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

I have a file

```
0,3,
7,2,0,
1,2,3,
1,2,
```

which should be

```
0,3,0,
7,2,0,
1,2,3,
1,2,0,
```

So how can I append each line with two commas with `0,`? I am interested in the most elegant solution and particularly interested if some script exists to help with such tasks, often required in manipulating CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant way I could think of would be with a substitute command.

Either of these would do the trick:

```
:%s/\v^(\d,){2}$/\00,
:%s/^\d,\d,$/\00,
```

This will replace any line containing two digits and commas with that whole line followed by "0,". If you would like to modify it to work with numbers more than 1-digit long, you could change it to:

```
:%s/\v^(\d+,){2}$/\00,
```

or

```
:%s/^\d\+,\d\+,$/\00,
```

Comment: What does `\v` mean? `\v` to stand for very magic making the characters to have special meaning so you don't have to escape the brackets? While `\V` turns off the very magic property, right? Found it here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic Nice command +1

Answer (score 1):

*I don't know if this qualifies as elegant or overkill but anyways... :)*

As an idealistic software dude whenever I see a problem like this I tend to think in terms of a general solution. Here's a script I just wrote that will determine the arbitrarily maximum number of columns in a CSV file and then pad out all the lines with fewer columns so they are the same size.

```
" Recursively look for line with most columns and return that number
func! MaxCsvCols(maxcols)
    " find next line with equal to or greater than maxcols columns
    let line = search('^\([^,]\+,\)\{' . a:maxcols . ',}$', 'W')
    if line != 0
        return MaxCsvCols(len(split(getline("."), ",")))
    else
        return a:maxcols
    endif
endfunc

func! PadCsv()
    call cursor(1, 1)
    let maxcols = MaxCsvCols(1)
    if maxcols < 2 | return | endif

    call cursor(1, 1)
    let linenum = 1
    while linenum > 0
        let newcols = maxcols - len(split(getline("."), ","))
        let newtext = getline(".") . repeat("0,", newcols)
        call setline(linenum, newtext)
        " find next line that has less-than maxcols columns
        let linenum = search('^\([^,]\+,\)\{,' . eval(maxcols-1) . '}$', 'W')
    endwhile
endfunc
```

With the cursor somewhere in this...

```
0,3,
7,2,0,
1,2,3,
7,2,0,9,
6,
1,2,3,2,2,
1,2,
```

...do `:call PadCsv()` and you get this...

```
0,3,0,0,0,
7,2,0,0,0,
1,2,3,0,0,
7,2,0,9,0,
6,0,0,0,0,
1,2,3,2,2,
1,2,0,0,0,
```

Of course this will work with your example, too.

*If there's a much easier way to do this in Vim I'd love to see it...but I probably would have written this anyways. I like to code. ;)*

Answer (score 0):

*A solution*

```
:g!/[0-9],[0-9],[0-9],/ s/$/0,/
```

where it matches all lines with two commas and three numbers. Then the bang `!` reverses it to get what wanted.

Comment: Two tips: 1) Surely you want `[0-9],` rather than `[0-9,]`. The second one includes the comma in the range, meaning it will match a digit or a comma. 2) Your regex could be way simplified: `:g!/\(\d,\)\{3}` or even `:g!/\v(\d,){3}`